# Для чего был придуман интерфейс DXGI

Tags: c++, directx

В `DiretX Api` начиная с версии `10`, присутствует интерфейс `DXGI`, именно `1.0`, не `1.1`. Хочу подробно узнать для чего он был придуман, и как правильно его использовать, а не только как интерфейс умеющий извлечь информацию о видеокарте и видеовыходах, и использования `IDXGISwapChain`.

Comment: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/direct3ddxgi/d3d10-graphics-programming-guide-dxgi